# F2py errors with a MAC M2

Tags: macos, fortran, arm64, f2py

I'm trying to use f2py on a MAC M2. My programs all run successfully on an Intel MAC. The first part of the process to produce C code from my Fortran source which seems to work but I get the following error when the C compilation attempts and fails

```
clang-14clang-14: : error: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=core2'the clang compiler does not support '-march=core2'
```

Followed by this long string

```
error: Command "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/condaTest/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/condaTest/include -arch arm64 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/include -ftrapping-math -DNPY_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION=1 -I/var/folders/np/393cjs953159dbj23mgqmlqr0000gn/T/tmpf0_vcv2d/src.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9 -I/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/condaTest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/condaTest/include/python3.9 -c /var/folders/np/393cjs953159dbj23mgqmlqr0000gn/T/tmpf0_vcv2d/src.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/fib3module.c -o /var/folders/np/393cjs953159dbj23mgqmlqr0000gn/T/tmpf0_vcv2d/var/folders/np/393cjs953159dbj23mgqmlqr0000gn/T/tmpf0_vcv2d/src.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/fib3module.o -MMD -MF /var/folders/np/393cjs953159dbj23mgqmlqr0000gn/T/tmpf0_vcv2d/var/folders/np/393cjs953159dbj23mgqmlqr0000gn/T/tmpf0_vcv2d/src.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/fib3module.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

I would be very grateful for any help with this.

Comment: Where does the `-march=core2` come from? Please follow [mcve]. What exact commands are you using? Note that core2 is for the x86_64 CPUs.

Comment: `-march=core2` is a compiler option sometime used with `gfortran`.  The `core2` part is telling the compiler to generate an executable tuned to the Intel Core 2 processor.  Doubt that runs on a Mac M2 unless you are using an emulation layer.

Comment: I followed the examples given in https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/f2py-examples.html and although the .c file was produced I get the error given above. I assume that the compiler I have as default (clang?) will not work and I need to know which compiler I should use and how to modify the the f2py command accordingly -many thanks for any further cd ~/Python/FBS_Examples/FBS_Relax